# Pandas separator function not working correctly

Tags: python, pandas

I am working on this dataset: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv

I am using this code to separate the data:

```
df = pd.read_csv('sugar.csv',header=None,sep=",",engine='python')
```

But this doesn't separate the contents.

Then I used :

```
df = pd.read_csv('sugar.csv',header=None,sep="\,",engine='python')
```

This seems to work fine but then there was `ï»¿"6` written on first row first column and the first and the last column are ending with `" "`.
Don't know what went wrong.
I have earlier used sep and it had worked fine but doesn't know what went wrong this time.
Need Help.

Comment: Try reinstalling pandas, sometime it doesn't installed properly i don't know why. btw, i have tried this it worked `df = pd.read_csv("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jbrownlee/Datasets/master/pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv", header=None, engine='python', sep=',')`

Comment: Try passing `encoding='utf-8-sig'`.

Comment: encoding = ''utf-8-sig' solved the ï»¿"6 part but still at the starting and ending " " are present. How to deal with them?

Comment: When I directly tried to separate the commas using the link, it's working fine, but when I am saving the data into csv file and then applying, it is still showing quotes at the front and back columns.

Comment: I just ran `df = pd.read_csv('pima-indians-diabetes.data.csv', header=None)` and it worked without issues.

Comment: try `df.replace('""', '', regex=True)`  or `df.coll.replace('""', '', regex=True)` and see if that helps.